# Best (quick) way to copy data from Azure Blob into Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

What's the best (and quick) way to copy data from Azure blob into Azure Data Lake storage? This copy is a one time job. The data set is about 50 G and includes about 10 files. Each file has about 20 columns.

I have looked at Azure Data Factory and it requires to create the datesets for each file in the Azure Data Factory. This is very tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AdlCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob) for copying Azure Storage Blobs in to Azure Data Lake Store.

Answer (score 1):

As a contemporary answer for those coming across this question.

It depends if you mean quick in terms of "speed to develop" or "speed to transfer".

I suspect speed to develop based upon your concerns with data factory.

Data Factory now has a "Copy Data Wizard" which makes it quick to setup these things.

Judging by the age of the question, this is likely in the Data Factory V1 timeframe. Data Factory V2 is out now and far easier.

[image: Copy Data Wizard]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool

In regards to the speed to transfer, Data Factory publishes the following stats, so it'll be around 105MB/s transfer speed, I suspect even faster.

[image: transfer speeds for data factory between blob storage and ADLS]

For Azure Data Lake Gen2, AdlCopy isn't mentioned in the documentation anymore, instead AzCopy is mentioned.

I realise you already have your question answered, but just in case people come across this in the future.

Comment: My problem with both ADF and AzCopy is that they require VM. AzCopy runs in command line and ADF needs to use Self-hosted Integration Runtime (that needs a node - VM).
MS announced Azure Data Share. It is currently in Preview. It is not available in my country yet, but someone may be more lucky. It should reach GA mid 2020.

Comment: Hi, that's true about AzCopy to a certain degree. But less so about ADF, the self-hosted integration runtime is only necessary if you intend to copy data from on-premise to the cloud or have other advanced needs such as IP restrictions, Microsoft supply an out of the box integration runtime fully managed by Microsoft. AzCopy does need infrastructure, but it could be run locally (particularly if your data is local), in "Az Cli" direct in the portal or in a Azure Container Instance meaning very little infrastructure to manage.

Comment: Azure Data Share does have benefits if doing simple copies and I suspect it's build on top of ADF (though couldn't tell for sure).

Comment: Well... I thought that I can go with default Azure... Int Runtime, but then I was getting Forbidden error. Took me some time, but then I've found this:

_"If you enable the "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" option on Azure Storage firewall settings, using Azure Integration Runtime to connect to Blob storage will fail with a forbidden error, as ADF is not treated as a trusted Microsoft service. Please connect via a Self-hosted Integration Runtime instead."_


From <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage>

Comment: Yes that's true, that's enabling the IP restrictions on the storage account. Without them the Azure managed Intergration Runtime is fine. I'd suggest opening another question if you have specific questions about Intergration Runtime as we're probably going off topic for the question.

Comment: Re: AzCopy
I am able to download from storage to a machine. I am also able to upload from machine to ADLS2. but when I try to copy from Blob to ADLS2 I get: "the inferred source/destination combination is currently not supported. Please post an issue on Github if support for this scenario is desired"